# List with duplicate entries

Tags: php, mysql, zend-framework

I got a minor problem. To start, I have the following tables: 'groups', 'pages' and the junction table 'subcriptions'

The idea behind this is that a group (with users) can subsribe to a page. An user can add a page as a subscription to the group he is in. (many-to-many). For information: An user can be in multiple groups.

As a part of the UI I want to make a list about that. From every group I want the associated pages. For example: (Group: ... Pages: -.... , -....  | Group: ... Pages: -...., -.... etc.)

The SQL query is not a issue:

```
SELECT Groups.name, pages.name, pages.id
FROM Groups
JOIN subscriptions ON groups.id = subscriptions.group_id
JOIN pages ON subscriptions.page_id = pages.id
WHERE groups.id IN ('1', '2')   // de values 1 & 2 zijn voorbeelden en stellen de groepen id's voor waarin de huidige gebruiker zit.
```

The result will, for example, look like this:

```
group name ---- page name ---- page id
group1 -------- page1 --------- 1
group1 -------- page2 --------- 2  
group2 -------- page1 --------- 1
```

My question is; how can I get a (html) list where I get a single group-name and all the associated pages to that group?  (Like the example I mentioned earlier). I need a php solution. (I am using Zend framework, but I could not find a solution in Zend that does the trick I want)

Or do have to do a single query for every group? I would like to avoid that though..

I am new in this world of mysql and php so every help is worth allot! Thanks. :)

Comment: .:so you want to get the page(s) available for every group?

Comment: Sounds like it's time to learn about domain models and data mappers. This is the same kind of question I had to answer and models and mappers seems to fit. http://phpmaster.com/building-a-domain-model/ and http://phpmaster.com/integrating-the-data-mappers/ ...Good Luck

Answer (score 1, accepted):

a very basic implementation would be the following:

- loop through mysql results
- build a 2-dimensional array with the group as your 1st and the associated pages as 2nd dimension
- in your html template, take your array and use an outer loop to go through your groups and an inner loop to get the pages per group

cheers :)

Comment: You mean something like this? Haven't tried it yet though.
$data = array(); 
foreach($result as $group => $page) { 
  $data[$group][] = $page; 
}

Comment: How would the loops in the html template look like? I've tried some things but can't figure it out yet.

Comment: would be something like foreach($data as $group => $pages) { /*... output group...*/ foreach($pages as $page) { /*... output pages ...*/} }